# Symfony2 How can user information be fetching by DQL?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

For example, suppose that an article is fetched.
User ID is attached to the article of the database at the time of creation.

```
$article->setAuthor($user_id);    // <- This is number, is not object.
```

This is the code which takes some articles.

```
public function find_all()
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                  ->createQuery('
                      SELECT a, r FROM MySampleBundle:Article a
                      LEFT JOIN a.reviews r
                      ORDER BY a.date_created DESC'
                  );
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

If it is only an author.

```
public function find_all($author)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                  ->createQuery('
                      SELECT a, r FROM MySampleBundle:Article a
                      LEFT JOIN a.reviews r
                      WHERE a.author = :author
                      ORDER BY a.date_created DESC'
                  )
                  ->setParameter('author', $author);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

What should I do to also have taken author information of some articles at this time?
I am using FOSUserBundle.
Should I do to relate article table to fos_user table?
Or is it possible by left join?

This is only one example of a failure.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
              ->createQuery('
                  SELECT a, r FROM MySampleBundle:Article a
                  LEFT JOIN a.reviews r
                  LEFT JOIN MyUserBundle:User u
                    WITH u.id = a.author
                  WHERE a.author = :author
                  ORDER BY a.date_created DESC'
              )
              ->setParameter('author', $author);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to define relation in the `Article` Entity to User by the `author` field
2. Then you will be able to do retrive Author data

   ```
   $author = $restult->getAuthor() // User Entity Class Object
   $authorName = $author->getName();
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Is it impossible if not related? Can't it take from ID number?

Comment: the code will be longer because you cannot get this data in just one query. It's possible but in conflict with an Art of programing.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Ouch, ouch...I have been mistaken in all the logic.